HomeAssistant / Ubuntu : cannot boot, how to point to EFI boot file?
i'm trying to install HomeAssistant OS on a old computer. This computer is compatible with UEFI.
In order to install HomeAssistant, I booted the computer with UBUNTU installed on a USB key and by selecting UEFI mode:

Then I installed HomeAssistant from the image provided on their website and I end up with this disk partition structure:

I see it's not mounted so I click on the play button to mount it.
I see that the bootfile is available here:

It is located in /media/ubuntu/...
I have tried to point to the EFI file by doing this:
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda1 --part 1 --label "haos2" \ --loader '\EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi'

and I get the following:

I'm not super familiar with Linux so I may have missed something at some point. I pointed to SDA1 but was that the right thing to do? Is there anything else I should change?
Thanks

Did you follow this guide? https://www.home-assistant.io/installation/generic-x86-64 Method 1 or 2? What step did you reach?

I used method one with Ubuntu installed on a USB drive and everything worked but the computer doesn't find the operating system when booting. That's why I try their suggestion with the efibootmgr to make sure it was pointing to the right efi file. That's where I'm stuck now. Thanks
